# Mysql select no relation from two tables

Tags: mysql, relation

I have two tables first one has `PRODUCTS_ID` and second table has the relation between products for example product 1 has relation with product (2,3,4,5) as shown in `PRODUCT_CONN`.
What I need to get the products listed on Table 1 that has no relation to product 1
then the result should be like that "6,7,8".

```
TABLE 1
========
PRODUCTS_ID
    1   
    2   
    3   
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8   

TABLE2
======
PRODUCT_ID  | PRODUCT_CONN
    1       |   2
    1       |   3
    1       |   4
    1       |   5
```

Answer (score 2):

One way you can do this, is joining both tables, and then filtering the rows for discard those that have relations with product **ID 1**, like in next example:

```
SELECT
    TABLE_1.PRODUCTS_ID
FROM
   TABLE_1
LEFT JOIN
   TABLE_2 ON TABLE_2.PRODUCT_CONN = TABLE_1.PRODUCTS_ID
WHERE
   TABLE_1.PRODUCTS_ID <> 1
AND
   (TABLE_2.PRODUCT_ID IS NULL OR TABLE_2.PRODUCT_ID <> 1)
```

Alternatively, you could first select all IDs that are connected to product with **ID 1**, and then select all IDs that are not in this set, excluding also product **ID 1**, like this:

```
SELECT
    PRODUCTS_ID
FROM
    TABLE_1
WHERE
    PRODUCTS_ID NOT IN (SELECT PRODUCT_CONN
                        FROM TABLE_2
                        WHERE PRODUCT_ID = 1)
AND
    PRODUCTS_ID <> 1;
```

Comment: Just a pedantic comment. I would use `<>` instead of `!=` for better compatiblity with standard SQL. Upvoted anyway.

Comment: Was waiting for the Join based solution ;) +1 . I think you can change the answer priority. Move **more efficient** join based solution to first and then subquery

Comment: Thanks for the feedback to both, going to apply changes.

Comment: @Mina please read here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. I assume could be because you don't write any attempt (or try) to resolve your issue.

Comment: Your welcome, i will appreciate if you mark the answer as correct if you have some time.